# What would be the design challenges of making a phone out of detachable blocks?

Tags: design, cellphone

A video about a phone concept called [Phonebloks](http://phoneblocks.com/) has been circulating 'round the web for a while now. It is a phone platform where generic "blocks" are connected via the "base", which is some kind of generic circuit which connects the blocks together. Blocks can vary in size and be be placed anywhere on the base as long as they fit, and it will result in a working device.

[image]
[image]

The inventor is adamant about the advantages of the phone's modularity: less waste, more customizeable, and easier repair. But they don't seem to give attention to the disadvantages there would be. What would be the design challenges and disadvantages of such a modular phone system as opposed to designing usual phones?

Comment: It depends on the requirements: how small, how fast, how much space, how much resolution, ... This question cannot be answered without a clear, common idea of the requirements.

Comment: Related discussion: http://www.eevblog.com/forum/crowd-funded-projects/phonebloks-modular-smartphone/ My take is that this is a bit too modular.

Comment: It feels to me that the person who came up with this idea is not an engineer..

Comment: The general consensus on Reddit seemed to be that it wouldn't work, but that is Reddit.

Comment: Some variation of the idea should be technically workable to a degree, but it's unlikely that it would be cost effective.

Comment: There was a company called Modu which tried to create a similar concept. You have a basic 3G phone/modem and add various jackets for your application.

Comment: Also, who would care to write the software so that it would work flawlessly with all the possible configurations? Even if this was feasible electrically, the software would surely be  an Achilles heel...

Comment: The software part is what made me think about this. I'm a software developer myself, and I thought "writing the software for that must be horrible, is it even possible to build the physical thing?". Consensus seems to be that it's a pretty bad idea.

Comment: The Onion had a good piece about "idea people" like this. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DkGMY63FF3Q

Comment: Briefly discussed in chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11215810#11215810

Comment: It's a tough idea, and if anything I imagine it might not end up **as** modular as they had intended it. However it means they'll have to try and find ways to standardize the input and output to the blocks. It's like a giant state machine of hardware. Where the pieces go, you don't know!

Comment: The fact that they labelled one of the blocks "speed" speaks volumes. And in the top right there appears to be a thermometer.

Comment: The best way to understand the problems with this idea is to look at the ifixit teardowns of modern mobiles. Observe the lack of spare space. Then draw a couple of mm boundary around all the components and imagine expanding them by that amount. Consider the size of the resulting phone. Also, the phoneblocks design doesn't seem to show a cover over the blocks, which means that the whole thing scatters itself all over the floor as soon as you drop it: the exact opposite of the gorilla glass indestructibility trend.

Comment: I actually don't think the software is the major sticking point - look at the variety of hardware on which linux runs and available drivers there, and consider that it's primarily vendor strategy games that keeps that flexibility from filtering through to  *consumer* Android phones.  Rather, the issue that is modularizing adds costs and inefficiencies in all of the physical and electrical interfaces, and prevents using multi-function chips, such as those that may do several or all of radios, or be the CPU + display controller, or in some generations even be the CPU + much of the radio.

Comment: I'd love to see how they expect that to pass all the regulatory hurdles. It's hard enough to pass PTCRB tests with a regular cellphone design and a carefully routed PCB.  Look where they've got the antenna.  And BTW, where is the cellular modem?  (And CPU, for that matter.)  I don't think the designer has ever seen the block diagram (or inside) of a real cellphone.